# c# : runtime code profiling - any existing libraries?

Tags: c#, performance, profiling, runtime

I have an application where the user can connect nodes together to perform realtime calculations.
I'd like to be able to show the user a CPU-usage percentage to show how much of available CPU-time is being used, and a per-node breakdown to be able to spot the problem-areas.

Are there any available open source implementations for a runtime profiler like this ?
I can write my own using System.Diagnostics.Process.TotalProcessorTime, stopwatches / performancecounters, but I'd rather go with something tried & tested that could maybe offer me more detailed information later if possible.

Edit:
I'm not looking for a stand-alone profiler since I want to show the realtime stats in the UI of my application.

Comment: It sounds like you just want the CPU usage per machine or process, not a detailed per method break down like a code profiler provides.

Comment: I want the total cpu usage in %, and the % per calculation-node. So getting the performance-counter on calculation-start and -end per node should be enough right now, but later on I might want to add more in-depth information on where the CPU-time's going.

Comment: Just display 100%.  If it is any less then there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: Just like programmers who use IF-statements are not really sure what they're doing ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try commercial [GlowCode](http://www.glowcode.com/) profiler that has such feature.

Or open source [SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/), but it is still in beta.

Comment: This is great as a standalone profiler, but I want to do the profiling in the app itself to show the realtime stats to the user in the app's UI.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running off a timer, like say 10 calculations per second, because otherwise you are simply using 100% of the CPU (unless you're also doing I/O).

Can you set an alarm-clock interrupt to go off at some reasonable frequency, like 10 or 100 Hz, independent of whatever else the program is doing, and even especially during I/O or other blocked time?

Then for each block just keep a count of how many times out of the last 100 interrupts it was active. That's your percent, and the cost of acquiring it is minimal.

Do blocks call each other as subroutines? In that case, on each interrupt, you may want to capture the call stack among blocks, and a block is "active" if it is somewhere on the stack, and it is "crunching" if it is at the end of the stack (not in the process of calling another block, and not in I/O). Then you have a choice on each block of indicating the percent of time it is "crunching" (which will not exceed 100% when summed over blocks) or "active" (which probably will exceed 100% when summed over blocks).

The value of the latter number is it doesn't tell you so much "where" the time is spent, it tells you "why". That can answer questions like "I see that *foo* is taking a lot of time, but how did I get *there*?" Same for I/O. That's a process too, it just takes place on other hardware. You don't want to ignore it, because if you do you could end up saying "How come I'm only using a small fraction of the CPU? What's the holdup?"

Comment: I'm not running off a timer, I'm calculating and rendering stuff which means I'm bound by the vertical refresh of the monitor, and other stuff takes time too (GPU for example).

Comment: @IUsedToBeAPygmy: Note that even though your timer/vsync is running at a high rate, the rate you take stack samples does not have to be high. It only needs to be uncorrelated with the other.